# Use selected user-profile service in SharePoint

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-userprofile

If I have four user-profile services in SharePoint.

How to select a specific user-profile service?

I wanted to get data from user-profile service 2.

More: [How to use selected User-profile service in SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982369/how-to-use-selected-user-profile-service-in-sharepoint)